# React Native background looping animations

Tags: reactjs, react-native, animation, frontend

I'm trying to make background parallax effect in react native. Most things I've googled are just swipe parallax effects so I decided to implement it on my own with Animated API. Problem is that I can't seem to find how to make background image repeat infintely. So that when the last part of the image moves out of the screen it comes out from the opposite part. I've also tried to use a duplicate image and animate it after the first one goes off the screen(using a listener) but somehow its' speed is different and the two images overlap instead of moving linearly. (I've checked the position/speed/easing and everything matches up) Any ideas?

```
export default function App() {
  const windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
  const hill3Width = Image.resolveAssetSource(hill3Pic).width;

  const hill3LeftPos = new Animated.Value((hill3Width - windowWidth) * -1)
  const hill3LeftPos2 = new Animated.Value((hill3Width * -1) - 1)

  let looped = false

  hill3LeftPos.addListener(({ value }) => {
    //make sure first pics' leftmost part is on the screen and animate next image only once
    if (value > 0 && !looped) {
      looped = true
      Animated.sequence([
        Animated.timing(
          hill3LeftPos2,
          {
            toValue: windowWidth,
            duration: 6000,
            easing: Easing.linear,
            useNativeDriver: false
          }
        )]).start()
    }
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    cycleHill3Animation()
  }, []);


  const cycleHill3Animation = () => {
    Animated.sequence([
      Animated.timing(
        hill3LeftPos,
        {
          toValue: windowWidth,
          duration: 6000,
          easing: Easing.linear,
          useNativeDriver: false
        }
      )
    ]).start(() => {
      // hill3LeftPos.setValue((hill3Width - windowWidth) * -1)
      // cycleHill3Animation()
    })
  }
  return (
    <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'black', flex: 1 }}>

      <Animated.View style={{ position: 'absolute', bottom: 0, left: hill3LeftPos }}>
        <Animated.Image
          style={styles.hill3}
          source={require('./assets/examplebackground.png')}
        />
      </Animated.View>
      <Animated.View style={{ position: 'absolute', bottom: 0, left: hill3LeftPos2 }}>
        <Animated.Image
          style={styles.hill3}
          source={require('./assets/examplebackground.png')}
        />
      </Animated.View>
    </View >


  );

}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  hill3: {
    bottom: 0
  }
});
```

Here are the gifs:
[Blank space when image goes off the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPv7e.gif)

And the second one:

[Second image overlaps the first one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRh8s.gif)

Answer (score 0):

There are several limitations with your code, especially not being able to use native animation since you are animating the left value of a view.
I have created this working example for you.
Make sure to put your own image, and set it's width properly in the code under imageWidth

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Animated,
    Easing,
    Image,
    View,
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
    animatedValue;

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.animatedValue = new Animated.Value(0);

        Animated.loop(
            Animated.sequence([
                Animated.timing(this.animatedValue, {
                    toValue: 1,
                    duration: 2000,
                    easing: Easing.linear,
                    useNativeDriver: true,
                }),
                Animated.timing(this.animatedValue, {
                    toValue: 0,
                    duration: 0,
                    easing: Easing.linear,
                    useNativeDriver: true,
                }),
            ]),
        ).start();
    }

    render() {
        const imageWidth = 205;
        const translateX = this.animatedValue.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 1],
            outputRange: [-imageWidth, 0],
        });

        return (
            <View style={{
                flex: 1,
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center',
            }}>
                <View style={{
                    width: imageWidth,
                    overflow: 'hidden',
                }}>
                    <Animated.View style={{
                        width: 2 * imageWidth,
                        flexDirection: 'row',
                        overflow: 'hidden',
                        transform: [{
                            translateX: translateX,
                        }],
                    }}>
                        <Image source={require('./image.png')} />
                        <Image source={require('./image.png')} />
                    </Animated.View>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

I used this image for the example: [image]